# How to get the First and Last Record of DB

Tags: mysql

How can I retrieve the first and last record from a table.

Note : I am not going do to order by

Comment: question makes no sense.....

Comment: +1 -> I may be a bit controversial here, but I think that once you're familiar with some the RDMBS and have run a significant number of SQL queries you know that there is no promise for rows order in a table unless your ORDER them intentionally. However how do beginners know that? It's completely natural projection that table has first and last row.

Comment: Responding to your edit: You have to sort if you want any semblence of order. Databases are not stored in order, and there is not a set order *unless specified by an `order by`*. Ergo, you've looked at an answer and then rejected it in the face of all evidence that you cannot do what you want without an `order by` clause or multiple subqueries. Both of those answers are here. Choose whichever one you find fits your needs best.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "first" and "last".

You can "ORDER BY" a specific column, and choose "LIMIT 1", and then "ORDER BY ... DESC" to get the reverse.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1
```

...and if you want both in the same query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: No reason! Depends if the question wants that or not. I'll edit :)

Answer (score 5):

Question doesn't really make sense, but, assuming you're talking about the first and last row from a table this would work but it'd be better to do as two separate queries and assumes you have a numeric ID column. MySQL example:

```
select * from test where id = (select max(id) from test)
union
select * from test where id = (select min(id) from test)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY 1
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

assuming your first column is the key

(well that would work in t-sql)